# ignoring variable declaration in java4

Tags: java

I have an application which has to be supported in java4 and java5. If it is java 5 execution env i want to add more functionality.

```
public class Test
{
    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;
    private ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture;

    private boolean java4ExecEnv;

    public Test()
    {
        in the manifest.mf file I have something like Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment, using this i am setting java4ExecEnv
        java4ExecEnv = true/false;
    }

    method1()
    {
        if(!java4ExecEnv)
            scheduledFuture = scheduler....
    }

    method2()
    {
        if(!java4ExecEnv)
            scheduledFuture....
    }
}
```

In the method1 and method2 I can avoid the calls to scheduler and scheduledFuture if it is a java4 version. But is there any way to avoid instance variable declaration(scheduler,scheduledFuture) if the execution environment is java4.

Or should I look for the alternative things which are supported in both java4 and 5.

Comment: I guess the problem is that those classes are not known at all in those older versions. Maybe you can put those things in separate classes that are not on the main class path but loaded later, after determining whether it's Java 1.4 or 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

> If it is java 5 execution env i want to add more functionality

Java 5 and Java 1.4 have different APIs. While there are mostly similarities, if you are planning to target a particular version, this has to be done at compile time and not in the code itself. You can use `System.getProperty` to get the version, but Java is not like C/C++ with conditional `#define`'s. So if code is compiled on a higher JRE, it's not going to run on a lower JRE.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some demo code that will run on both Java 1.4 and Java 5:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Demo implements Runnable {
  public void run() { System.out.println("Executing"); }

  public static interface Runner { void run(Runnable r); }

  private static class Runner4 implements Runner {
    public void run(Runnable r) {
      System.out.println("Java 1.4");
      new Thread(r).start();
    }
  }

  private static class Runner5 implements Runner {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    public void run(Runnable r) {
      System.out.println("Java 5");
      executor.submit(r);
    }
  }

  public static Runner loadRunner() {
    try {
      Demo.class.forName("java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService");
      return new Runner5();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      return new Runner4();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) { loadRunner().run(new Demo()); }
}
```

This code must be compiled using Java 5 or above with a [target](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#crosscomp-options) version of 1.4. It checks the classpath for the *ExecutorService* type and falls back to an alternative if it is not present.

If this is a non-trivial project I would make the Java 5 dependent code into some sort of optional plugin and compile the bulk of the code against the Java 1.4 runtime library.